# If_test() - Dynamic Circuits in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming

I am trying to run a dynamic circuit by having mid-measurement in my code as follows:

```
from qiskit import *
from math import *
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeJakarta

backend = FakeJakarta()

q0 = QuantumRegister(1)
q1 = QuantumRegister(1)
c  = ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q0, q1, c)
result_ = []
for i in range(2):
    qc.ry(2*pi/3, q0)
    qc.cx(q0, q1)
    qc.h(q1)
    qc.measure(q1, c[i])
    with qc.if_test((c[i], 0)) as _else:
        result_.append(0)
    with _else:
        result_.append(1)
job = backend.run(qc)
print(result_)
```

As it is obvious we must have a result like [0, 1, 0]. However, the list that I receive always is [0, 1, 0, 1]. Does anyone know how to solve this matter?

Comment: Do you mind writing the rest of your code? Not sure what this suppose to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I completed the code as you can see it.

Comment: Could you please clarify your objective with this circuit? Are you trying to create a list that dynamically changes based on the quantum measurement results within each iteration of your loop? Or are you attempting to modify the quantum circuit's behavior based on previous measurement outcomes?

Comment: The goal which I am seaking to achieve in here is that I am trying to gather measurement data from each iteration. For example, if we consider three iterations, what we should have is something like [1, 0 , 1] , But it gives us [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there's a misunderstanding regarding the use of `if_test` and `_else` constructs in your code. In Qiskit, these constructs are for adding conditional quantum operations to the circuit based on classical register states, not for controlling the flow of Python code execution. Consequently, in your loop, both `result_.append(0)` and `result_.append(1)` are executed in each iteration, leading to a list that's twice as long as expected. Also, you should only expect a list of length two as your result (not three), as you are measuring with classical bit `c[0]` in the first iteration, and `c[1]` in the second iteration.

Here's a (potential) version of your code that gathers measurement data from each iteration (if I am correct in interpreting this you want to do):

```python
from qiskit import *
from math import *
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeJakarta

backend = FakeJakarta()

q0 = QuantumRegister(1)
q1 = QuantumRegister(1)
c  = ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q0, q1, c)

results = []

for i in range(2):
    qc.ry(2*pi/3, q0)
    qc.cx(q0, q1)
    qc.h(q1)
    qc.measure(q1, c[i])
    job = backend.run(qc, shots=1)
    result = job.result().get_counts(qc)
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice explanation. I have found an alternative that can do my proposed task. SwitchCase operation will the best and only option!